# how to make right button of react native drawer?

Tags: react-native

[image]

I made a right menu using react-native-drawer.
But I can't move left button to the right side as marked in the above picture.
Is there a way for it?

Comment: what you are using for the header ? navigator or navigatoriOS?

Comment: I have used react-native-drawer and react-native-router-flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the nav bar built into react-native-router-flux you can write your own [custom navbar](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/d75c6807cb5dd4f22f73ba70b81f2bf13a450ea5/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md#navigation-bar).  You can reference [their navigation component](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/4957320e0eb638be660aa97d142dd617d3a59569/src/NavBar.js) if you need to for help in doing so.  This will give you control to put the hamburger icon on the right.  Say you your component NavBar you then reference at follows when you define your router.

```
<Router 
  navBar={NavBar}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thank you 
Could you share me some code snippet?
I need only changing position to right side and want keep to default action that user click that, it appears right side menu.

Comment: You could largely copy their navbar component as the foundation of your own, just make sure you adjust the import statements .  There are a couple ways you can accomplish this you can start by looking at [line 484](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/4957320e0eb638be660aa97d142dd617d3a59569/src/NavBar.js#L484).  For example do you also want the back nav arrow to be on the right? You could replace renderLeftButton & renderBackButton styling to use rightButtonStyles or update to using renderRightButton with the hamburger image.

Answer (score 0):

For react-native-drawer:

```
<Drawer
    ...
    side={'right'}
>
    ... menu items here ...

</Drawer>
```

Comment: Please check my image. I already set the same. The menu has appeared from right. What I need is right button.